# GNU make is adding white space after -I (shared directory) option

Tags: makefile, arm, gnu-make, armclang

I'm trying to use armclang compiler through a GNU makefile, but there is a clash between both tools when using -I option.

For armclang compiler, the -I means "Adds the specified directory to the list of places that are searched to find included files.Syntax -Idir" without a space.

For GNU makefile ‘-I dir’ has the same meaning (but with a space).

in My makefile I have the following:

```
$(aarch32_bootobj): %.o: %.s
     @echo " [ASM ] $<"
     @armclang --target=armv8a-arm-none-eabi -Icommon/shared -c $< -o $@
```

When Running the Makefile, I'm getting the following Warning and Error :

```
    armclang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I common/shared'
    aarch32/shared/bootcode.s:32:10: error: Could not find include file 'boot_defs.hs'
```

Where boot_defs.hs exists under common/shared

When running the same armclang command outside the makefile, it works. therefore I'm assuming that makefile has formatted the -Icommon/share option and added automatic space just after the -I.

Is there any way to run the armclang command correctly? in other worlds, is it possible to let the makefile parse the -Icommon/shared without any automatic formatting?

I have been trying a lot of tricks to workaround that without any success.

Thanks a lot In advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU make doesn't split the `-Icommon/shared` option, and even if it did `armclang` would be able to parse that. If you remove the `@` from the `armclang` call in the Makefile, you'll see exactly what `make` does and that the `-Icommon/shared` parameter remains intact.

Your problem is with `armclang`; see [this bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21000) on the tracker. It doesn't pass `-I` flags to its integrated assembler. A workaround, then, should be to pass `-no-integrated-as` to `armclang`:

```
     @armclang -no-integrated-as --target=armv8a-arm-none-eabi -Icommon/shared -c $< -o $@
```

If that doesn't work, replace the `.include` directive with `#include` and either rename your asm files to `.S` (upper-case `S`), which indicates that they need C preprocessing, or pass `armclang` the `-x assembler-with-cpp` flag. The behavior of this is documented [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0773a/chr1383143887630.html).

Comment: Thanks A lot Wintermute. This is a great analysis. The  "-no-integrated-as" is not supported by armclang version 6.01 (version that I must use), while the -x assembler-with-cpp is working.